# Showing size grip in CDialog?

Tags: winapi, mfc, resize

I have seen code which handles the drawing of this thing (`DFCS_SCROLLSIZEGRIP`), but surely there is a window style which I can apply to get it "for free".  Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In lieu of a better answer, I will post the code I have that draws the size grip and handles the hit-testing.  You also need to invalidate the appropriate area during OnSize in order to get it repainted.

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    if (CDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC))
    {
        // draw size grip
        CRect r;
        GetClientRect(&r);
        int size = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
        r.left = r.right - size;
        r.top = r.bottom - size;
        pDC->DrawFrameControl(&r, DFC_SCROLL, DFCS_SCROLLSIZEGRIP);
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

-

```
LRESULT CMyDialog::OnNcHitTest(CPoint point)
{
    // return HTBOTTOMRIGHT for sizegrip area
    CRect r;
    GetClientRect(&r);
    int size = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);
    r.left = r.right - size;
    r.top = r.bottom - size;
    ScreenToClient(&point);

    if (r.PtInRect(point))
    {
        return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
    }
    else
        return CDialog::OnNcHitTest(point);
}
```

Source: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.ui/2006-01/msg00103.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to OnEraseBkgnd and OnNcHitTest mentioned by the above you will need to invalidate the grip area when the window sized, otherwise it will leave marks when enlarged:

```
void CMyDialog::OnSize(UINT nType, INT cx, INT cy)
{

    CRect  rc;
    int    iSize=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL);

    GetClientRect(rc);
    InvalidateRect(CRect(rc.left-iSize, rc.bottom-iSize, rc.right, rc.bottom), FALSE);
    CDialog::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a default style to get this functionality for free. You have to create a new child window with class name `Scrollbar` and control style [SBS_SIZEGRIP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787533(VS.85).aspx)